# gmaps4rails - categorize markers list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails, markers, categorization

Is there a way how to categorize markers list in sidebar? For example list for people, places, bus stations, etc. I would like to add lists separately. I hope that I descriped problem well.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. In controller

```
@json = your_scope.to_gmaps4rails do |marker, object|
  marker.json({ category: object.category }) # I assume you have the category info in a category method
end
```

Then you'll have to create the sidebar yourself, in the callback:

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
    if (this.markers[i].category == "foo")
    { addMarkerToFooList(this.markers[i]);}
    ...  
  }
};
```

Take inspiration [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/public/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js#L348) for sidebar creation.